# Pyspark add or remove rows in a dataframe based on another similar dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Consider that I have two Dataframes DF1 and DF2 with the same schema.
what I want to do is that :

For each row in DF1,

if DF1.uniqueId exists in DF2 and type is new, then add to DF2 with a repeat count.

if DF1.uniqueId exists in DF2 and type is old, change DF2 type to that of DF1 type (old).

if DF1.uniqueId does not exists in DF2 and type is new, add a new row to DF2.

if DF1.uniqueId does not exist in DF2 and type is old, move that row to a new table -DF3

ie. if the tables are as shown below, the resultant or the updated DF2 should be like resultDF2 table below

DF1

```html
+----------+--------------------------+
|UniqueID  |type_                     |
+----------+--------------------------+
|1         |new                       |           
|1         |new                       |      
|1         |new                       |
|2         |old                       |
|1         |new                       |
+----------+--------------------------+
```

DF2

```html
+----------+--------------------------+
|UniqueID  |type_                     |
+----------+--------------------------+
|          |                          |
+----------+--------------------------+
```

---

---

resultDF2

```html
+----------+--------------------------++----------+--------------------------+
|UniqueID  |type_                     |          repeatCount                 |
+----------+--------------------------++----------+--------------------------+
|    1     |   new                    |                    3                 |
+----------+--------------------------++----------+--------------------------+
```

resultDF3

```html
+----------+--------------------------++----------+--------------------------+
|UniqueID  |type_                     |          repeatCount                 |
+----------+--------------------------++----------+--------------------------+
|    1     |   old                    |                    0                 |
+----------+--------------------------++----------+--------------------------+
```

** if there is only one entry repeatCount is zero.

I am trying to achieve this using pyspark.
Can anyone please suggest me with any pointers on how to achieve this considering that I have both the tables in-memory.

Comment: Can you clarify the conditions a bit more? What happens if a uniqueID has both new and old `type_` in the dataframe?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that, if the dataframe(DF1) has new and old type_ for the same uniqueId then they are to be cancelled out as a pair.

Answer (score 2):

The desired output can be obtained by:

1. Group `df1` on `UniqueId` and get `repeatCount`, during this operation remove `UniqueId` that have `old` and `new` `type_`.
2. Apply a `Full Join` between dataframe from step 1 and `df2`.
3. From the joined result, remove rows where `df.UniqueId` is absent from `df2` and `df1.type_` is `old`.
4. Finally, select the `UniqueID`, `type_` and `repeatCount`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [(1, "new",), # Not exists and new
        (1, "new",),
        (1, "new",),
        (2, "old",), # Not exists and old
        (1, "new",),
        (3, "old",), # cancel out
        (3, "new",), # cancel out
        (4, "new",), # one entry count zero example
        (5, "new",), # Exists and new
        (6, "old",), ] # Exists and old
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("UniqueID", "type_", ))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(5, "new", ), (6, "new", ), ], ("UniqueID", "type_", ))

df1_grouped = (df1.groupBy("UniqueID").agg(F.collect_set("type_").alias("types_"), 
                                           (F.count("type_") - F.lit(1)).alias("repeatCount"))
                  .filter(F.size(F.col("types_")) == 1) # when more than one type of `type_` is present they cancel out
                  .withColumn("type_", F.col("types_")[0])
                  .drop("types_")
              )

id_not_exists_old = (df2["UniqueID"].isNull() & (df1_grouped["type_"] == F.lit("old")))

(df1_grouped.join(df2, df1_grouped["UniqueID"] == df2["UniqueID"], "full")
            .filter(~(id_not_exists_old))
            .select(df1_grouped["UniqueID"], df1_grouped["type_"], "repeatCount")
).show()

"""
+--------+-----+-----------+
|UniqueID|type_|repeatCount|
+--------+-----+-----------+
|       1|  new|          3|
|       4|  new|          0|
|       5|  new|          0|
|       6|  old|          0|
+--------+-----+-----------+
"""
```

Comment: Thanks @nithish , one thing is that since unique id 5 is already there in df2 table the final result need to have repeatCount 1 against uniqueId5.

Comment: @AlbinChandy so for `df1` `repeatCount` is `count(UniqueID) - 1` but for `df2` it's just `count(UniqueID)`? Also would `df2` also have cancelation?

Comment: the thing is df2 is a master table with all the type 'new' items, df1 is the batch which repeats periodically and is to be inserted into df1 after combining the repeated ones and yes, df2 also have cancellation. type 'old' can be retained on a separate dataframe.
For eg. if df1 uniqId 01 has a new with count 2 and the df2 already has 01 with count 03, then the resulting table has repeatCount 5 against uniq id 01

Comment: @AlbinChandy i'd suggest updating the question with a complete example of possible conditions and what the expected output would be, otherwise its difficult to understand the logic.

Comment: Hi @Nitish, I have posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70640200/pyspark-compare-rows-within-the-same-group-and-formulate-new-columns-based-on-t

can you please have a look if thats ok with you.